# getting the average duration over a group of splunk transactions

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

So I have some data in the format of

```
Time                | UUID           |  event_name_status            | actual_important_log_time 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-03-26T12:00:00 | 123456789      |  car_end                      | 2020-03-25T16:50:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00 | 123456789      |  car_mid                      | 2020-03-25T16:40:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00 | 123456789      |  car_start                    | 2020-03-25T16:30:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00 | 123456788      |  car_end                      | 2020-03-25T15:50:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00 | 123456788      |  car_mid                      | 2020-03-25T15:20:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00 | 123456788      |  car_start                    | 2020-03-25T14:50:30
```

Which Is a consistent pattern with each transaction having a start, mid and end with a different UID per transaction (also different vehichles for other transactions).

I currently group them into transactions using the following search command.

```
* | transaction UUID startswith="car_start" endswith="car_end"
```

Which groups the transactions showing how many there were in the last X length of time (could be hundreds/thousands in a day.

I need to get the duration of each transaction using the **actual_important_log_time** field and then use these values to get the average

Answer (score 0):

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="Time,UUID,event_name_status,actual_important_log_time
2020-03-26T12:00:00,123456789,car_end,2020-03-25T16:50:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00,123456789,car_mid,2020-03-25T16:40:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00,123456789,car_start,2020-03-25T16:30:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00,123456788,car_end,2020-03-25T15:50:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00,123456788,car_mid,2020-03-25T15:20:30
2020-03-26T12:00:00,123456788,car_start,2020-03-25T14:50:30"
| multikv forceheader=1
| table Time,UUID,event_name_status,actual_important_log_time
| foreach *time [ eval <<FIELD>> = strptime('<<FIELD>>', "%FT%T")]
| stats range(actual_important_log_time) as duration by UUID Time
| eval duration=tostring(round(duration),"duration")
| rex field=duration mode=sed "s/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/\1h \2m \3s/g"
```

This query makes duration by each UUID.
Now, I make duration to readable.
If you want to aggregate average, change `Time` to epoch and rename as `_time` after `stats`.
and use `timechart`